# How to make coordinate of positive numbers in java

Tags: java

```
I have an input of 
-157,118
-170,12
-74,139
-144,42
-155,196
122,-88
-187,-143
156,-18
-67,126
44,-102
....
```

like this .I have to check each number in a file(where i have more inputs like these) and have to find which pair belongs to (+ve,+ve).plese anyone help me .I am able to read the numbers from file .I have done this..

```
public class EulerGift {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // List<String> coordinateList=new ArrayList<String>();
    File file = new File("D:/coordinate.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            String value = sc.next();

            String[] tokens = value.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {

                    System.out.println("("+Integer.parseInt(tokens[i])+")");
                   // System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.format("File Not Found");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show us the code where you are reading numbers from the file... you can check there only whether it is number or not..

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question. What is +ve ? I'm assuming this is homework. Are you asking how to open a file ? Or how to compare two values? From the way the question is asked, it could be either.

Comment: @spuder I thought they were asking how to accept only values that are both positive :P

Comment: yes i am asking how to find the pair which is positive

Comment: try my answer... it will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the positive pair:

```
String value = sc.next();
String[] tokens = value.split(",");
int[] values = new int[2];

values[0] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0])
values[1] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])
if(values[0]>0 && values[1]>0)
    System.out.println("(" + values[0] + "," + values[1] + ")");
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this needs to explain their reasoning. I do not see anything wrong with this answer.